# Recoverable Error: Object of class Credis_Client could not be converted to string

Tags: xml, redis, cm-redissession

I'll add items to the cart and then they will disappear. I don't have too much more information at this point.

line 374 is the last line here:

```
if ($lock != 1) {
                    $this->_log(sprintf(
                        "Successfully broke lock for ID %s after %.5f seconds (%d attempts). Lock: %d\nLast request of broken lock: %s",
                        $sessionId, (microtime(true) - $timeStart), $tries, $lock, $this->_redis->hGet($sessionId, 'req')
                    ), Zend_Log::INFO);
```

No other errors in the system.log

Exception.log has two errors that may affect the Credis_Client

```
tail -f exception.log 
#4 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(196): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(582): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
#6 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#7 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /home/magento/master/html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#10 /home/magento/master/html/shell/scheduler.php(377): Mage::dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#11 /home/magento/master/html/shell/scheduler.php(37): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->cronAction()
#12 /home/magento/master/html/shell/scheduler.php(403): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->run()
#13 {main}
```

Swarming had built a module and this could be the issue cause it's 404'ing

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'API Request Failed: 404 returned.' in /home/magento/master/html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/local/Swarming/Erp/Model/Abstract/Connector.php(152): Mage::throwException('API Request Fai...')
#1 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/local/Swarming/Erp/Model/Abstract/Connector.php(180): Swarming_Erp_Model_Abstract_Connector->post(true)
#2 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/local/Swarming/Erp/Model/Observer.php(277): Swarming_Erp_Model_Abstract_Connector->postData(Array)
#3 [internal function]: Swarming_Erp_Model_Observer->syncSubmissionQueue(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#4 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(196): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(582): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
#6 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#7 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /home/magento/master/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /home/magento/master/html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#10 /home/magento/master/html/shell/scheduler.php(377): Mage::dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#11 /home/magento/master/html/shell/scheduler.php(37): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->cronAction()
#12 /home/magento/master/html/shell/scheduler.php(403): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->run()
#13 {main}
```

**Magento ver. 1.14.2.2**